# Python service has troubles in Windows Services

Tags: python, windows, service

I am finding several problems when running a python service in Windows. This is my progress so far:

1. I could install my python service with `python main.py install`.
2. I see my python service listed on Windows Services.
3. The first time I hit "Run" a 1053 error appeared which was solved by adding some python paths to the `SystemPath` environment variable.
4. Hitting "Run" again I got this message in Event Log Viewer:

   ```
   The instance's SvcRun() method failed 
   <Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed %2: %3
   ```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020274/facing-error-when-python-exe-service-is-started-after-nssm#comment114952659_65020274)

Answer (score 0):

In the instance of `SVCRun()` you need an try, catch sentence

for example

```py
try: # try main
            self.main()
        except:
            servicemanager.LogErrorMsg(traceback.format_exc()) # if error print it to event log
            os._exit(-1)#return some value other than 0 to os so that service knows to restart
```

Go to [How to keep a windows service running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5315193/) for more info